# Using the JDK LDAP library, how can I add more than one description?

Tags: java, ldap

I can add two descriptions (attribute) using my IDE, but from Java I can only add one description. How to add the second one?

I'm using the JDK LDAP library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries I was able to do it myself

```
Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
BasicAttribute b = new BasicAttribute("description");
b.add("a");
b.add("b");
attrs.put(b);
```

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself, you should accept this answer